# JavaScript: How To Count Total Number Of Heads and Tails In Random Coin Flip Within Associative Array?

Tags: javascript, loops, associative-array, coin-flipping

I have an array that has two other associative arrays within it:

```
 var coinToss = [];

 coinToss["FlipNumber"]; coinToss["Result"];
```

I already have the randomizer function working and everything.  I just need help on totaling the sum of all 'heads' and 'tails'.

I tried doing:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < coinToss.length; i++)
 {
      var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

      if (coinToss["Result"] === 'heads')
            headCount++;
      else
            tailCount++;
 }
 document.getElementByID.innerHTML += "Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount + "<br>";
```

But it only prints out each separate results such as, for example for 5 coin flips:

```
 //*Heads: 1   Tails: 0 *
 //*Heads: 1   Tails: 0 *
 //*Heads: 0   Tails: 1 *
 //*Heads: 1   Tails: 0 *
 //*Heads: 0   Tails: 0 *
```

What I want is to add up all the 'heads' and add up all the 'tails' separately.  How come it resets back to 0 every time the loop reiterates?

EDIT as requested:

```
 function coinFlip() {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0) ? 'heads' : 'tails';
 }

 for (var x = 0; x < 6 (/*i.e. number of coin toss*/); x++)
 {
     var coinToss = [];
     coinToss["flipNumber"] = /*varies by user input*/;
     coinToss["Result"] = (coinFlip());

     /*a print code that prints Flip Number: () and Result: ()*/
 }
```

Comment: You're not accessing the array elements in your loop. You need to use the index `i` somewhere.

Comment: Please edit your post into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For example, there is neither a coin tossing function, nor example data to sum.  It is difficult to get a correct answer without one of those.

Comment: I just recently added  the full code at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```js
// Make sure you're declaring your variables outside of the for loop:

// I'm not sure what your actual array looks like, but let's say it looks something like this:
var arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
arr["Result"] = "heads";
var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr["Result"] === "heads")
        headCount += arr[i];
    else
        tailCount += arr[i];
}
console.log("Heads: " + headCount + " " + "Tails: " + tailCount);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more simpler way using a loop... I'm just a novice beginner at Javascript...

Comment: Oh, so should I create an Object first?  The "Results" will vary though since it will depend on the coinFlip() function that I implemented:

Answer (score -1):

```
//* these variables should be initialised outside the loop
//* otherwise they'll get initialised with zero each time the loop runs

var headCount = 0, tailCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < coinToss.length; i++) {

  if (coinToss["Result"] === 'heads')
        headCount++;
  else
        tailCount++;
 }

document.getElementByID.innerHTML += "Heads: " + headCount + " " +     "Tails: " + tailCount + "<br>";
```